# Circle to polyline

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, path

I am using Maptiler's static map - https://documentation.maptiler.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020805897-Static-maps-for-your-web - to generate a static map.

I am trying to draw a simple map with a semi-transparent circle overlay. Like in the picture below. I want this circle to be exactly 300 meters in radius.

[image]

The API doesn't allow drawing polygons, but it allows drawing paths with a series of lng,lat points. Is there a straight forward way to generate a path given a point and a radius?

Comment: It's a partial differential equation only solvable by iterative means. The only direct way to do this is via a code library.